# Set hidden form field on submit

Tags: webforms

I have two select form fields on a webform. The first `'country'` is a list of country codes / country names and the second `'recipient'` is a hidden field which contains county codes and email recipients.

```
GB|United Kingdom
US|United States

GB|gb-address@example.com
US|us-address@example.com
```

I may have several countries with the same email recipient (hence having to use two lists and not just one mapping recipient|country). I would like to set the value for the second field based on the value of the first upon submitting the form. I have tried a few times with no success.

So far, my code is as follows:

```
function my_enquiry_form_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if($form_id == 'webform_client_form_11566') {

    $form_state['my_recipients'] = $form['submitted']['recipient']['#options'];
    $form['submitted']['recipient']['#access'] = FALSE;

    $form['#submit'][] = 'my_enquiry_form_form_submit';
  }
}


function my_enquiry_form_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  // ## some code removed ##
  $formRecipient = 'test-email@domain.com';

  // Update the recipient value
  $form['submitted']['recipient']['#value'] = $formRecipient;

  $form_state['values']['submitted'][5] = $formRecipient;
  $form_state['values']['submitted_tree']['recipient'] = $formRecipient;

  $form_state['complete form']['submitted']['recipient']['#value'] = $formRecipient;

  form_set_value($form['submitted']['recipient'],array('und' => array(0 => array('value' => $formRecipient))),$form_state);
}
```

Comment: If I remember correctly it may be a submit handler order issue. Try to make sure yours is run first by adding it to the submit handlers with array_unshift. This is of course assuming that your submit handler is firing.

Comment: It does fire as I have been printing out the values of $form and $form_state with die(); I think I'm perhaps not using form_set_value correctly and don't think I should be setting values on $form_state manually.